# What's the correct syntax for variable inequalities in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, inequalities

I'm a bit new to bash so please excuse any naive questions or nooby stuff I do.

So I wrote a quick script that lists all tput colors, and it works pretty well. It looks like this:

`unset x; for i in {1..256}; do tput setab $x; echo $x; x=$((x+1)); done`

But I wanted to use less than/equal to instead of what I did above. I tried doing a bunch of stuff like this:

`unset x; if [ $x -le 256] ; do tput setab $x ; echo $x ; x=$((x+1)) ; done`

And this:

`unset x; if [ $x -le 256] then do tput setab $x ; echo $x ; x=$((x+1)) ; done`

But I can't get the syntax right, it just says unexpected token "done" or "do". Google didn't help me, nor did I find anything that answered my questions here on Stack Overflow. Also I'd like to be able to have it unset x after it reaches 256 and then keep repeating the script so it could look trippy. So yeah, if anyone could help I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if` block cannot be the condition for a `do` loop. Use `while` instead. Also, when you `unset x`, `$x` will be undefined and cannot be compared to a number. I suppose you actually want something like this:

```
unset x
x=1
while [ $x -le 256 ]; do
  tput setab $x
  echo $x
  x=$((x+1))
done
```

The last expression (`x=$((x+1))`) could be simplified to `((x++))`. And, as Uwe pointed out, there must be whitespace before and after square brackets (except between a closing square bracket and a semicolon), otherwise `bash` won't be able to parse the statement correctly.

However, if you just increment `$x` with every cycle of the loop, this approach has no advantage whatsoever over a `for` loop:

```
for x in {1..256}; do
  tput setab $x
  echo $x
done
```

Comment: By the way, note that there are spaces around `[` and `]`. These are mandatory (except for the space between `]` and `;`, which is optional).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I decided to use the for loop you included, as it's (obviously) better than what I had. I also feel proud of myself for making a bit of a messy solution for a repeating tput rainbow using your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Only for completeness, you can write your 1st example as:

```
for i in {1..256}
do
        tput setab $i
        echo $i
done
```

So, you can use directly the `$i` and don't need use/increment the `$x`.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! As I said I'm quite naive with bash still.